Source for Korbanos Tzibbur being made by ישראלים
The כלי חמדה in his first piece on Parshas Bamidbar mentioned a concept of כל היכא דאפשר לאהדורי אטהרה מהדרין.loosely translated, whenever possible we try to find (use) the most Tahor.
In the context of the כלי חמדה, it means that if all Kohanim are טמאים (unpure), we would have ישראלים do the קרבנות ציבור in the bais hamikdash.
What is the source of this halacha?
